# Microsoft SQL Server max of character and numeric values in same column

Tags: sql-server, max

I am taking the max of a column that contains both numeric and `varchar` values (i.e. '2008', 'n/a'). What is considered the max? The string or numeric value?

I am working in Microsoft SQL Server.

Thanks!

Comment: `'2008'` is a string, not a number.  The column cannot be both a `varchar` and `numeric` datatype.  It is using string comparison.  So for your example, `'n/a'` is the max of the two.

Comment: you're right. so which of those 2 values are taken as the max?

Comment: `'n/a'` would be the max of the two.

Answer (score 1):

> For character columns, MAX finds the highest value in the collating sequence.
>   - [`max()` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql)

It will be the same value as if you `order by col desc`

---

Here are some values thrown into a column and sorted descending:

```
+------------+
|    col     |
+------------+
| Z          |
| na         |
| n/a/       |
| 9999999999 |
| 30         |
| 2008       |
| 00000000   |
+------------+
```

The `max()` would be the first value from the above. `Z`.

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/IXXX76837

---

The exact order will depend on your the collation of your column (most default to Latin1_General_CI_AS).

Here is a demo that shows you the sort order for each character for some different collations (latin general / latin binary)

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WLJ38844

Answer (score 1):

The Numeric value is actually a string.

MAX finds the highest value in the collating sequence

For collating sequence of ASCII chars refer below link.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQ2R2_9.5.1/com.ibm.ent.cbl.zos.doc/PGandLR/ref/rlebcasc.html

Answer (score -1):

```
create table one
(
Col1 varchar(200)
)
insert into one(Col1)
values('2008'),('n/a'),('aaaa'),('bbb'),('zzzz')

select max(Col1) from one
--zzzz
```

Comment: How does this answer their question?

Comment: Just gave example, when they are mix of numbers and strings when doing max, doe not it make sense

Answer (score -1):

n/a would be max

It is better to eliminate the known 'n/a' values and cast them to some thing meaningful while applying the max or min functions.

```html
select max(cast(column as int)) 
from tablename
where column != 'n/a'
```